# Add Random Header value for every request in Gatling

Tags: gatling

I am trying to send a random correlation-id header value for every HTTP request made by Gatling using their Java API

Here is my code so far but it sends the same correlation-id everytime.

```
/* imports */

public class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {

  {
    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
      .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/app")
      .inferHtmlResources()
      .contentTypeHeader("application/json")      
    
    Map<CharSequence, String> headers_0 = new HashMap<>();
    headers_0.put("service", "orders");


    ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
      .exec(
        http("request_0")
          .post("/getorder")
          .headers(headers_0)
          .header("correlation-id", "test-"+ UUID.randomUUID())
          .body(RawFileBody("recordedsimulation/0000_request.json"))
      );

    setUp(scn.injectOpen(constantUsersPerSec(20).during(Duration.ofMinutes(1))))
            .protocols(httpProtocol)
            .throttle(
                    reachRps(40).in(1),
                    holdFor(Duration.ofMinutes(5)),
                    jumpToRps(40),
                    holdFor(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/function/): here, you're passing a value to the `header` method, so indeed, it's a static value.

Instead, you want to pass a function (even if you don't use the Session input parameter) so it's evaluated on each execution:

```java
.header("correlation-id", session -> "test-"+ UUID.randomUUID())
```